# WebView variables android

Tags: android, variables, webview

Hello I can't resolve this problem. I want to read a variable in method `onSwipeBottom()` from `showToast()`. I am a newbie in OOP so if you can please help me.

I want open another page on swipe.

OpenNews.js

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_open_news);


        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(webview);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "android");

        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.exaple.com");
        if(k != ""){
        myWebView.loadUrl(k);
        }
}

/*this is declared before but is no matter we can use even sapmle()*/
public void onSwipeBottom() {
     //WANT READ HERE var VALUE
     String k = var;
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, OpenNews.class);
     startActivity(intent);
}

public class WebAppInterface {
     Context mContext;

     /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
     WebAppInterface(Context c) {
         mContext = c;
     }

     /** Show a toast from the web page */
     @JavascriptInterface
     public void showToast(String toast) {
        //Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        String var = toast;
        Log.d("", var); //here i have log in console with address from html file, everything is ok and work propertly. 
     }
}
}
```

---

HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidToast(toast) {
        android.showToast(toast);
    }

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    showAndroidToast('http://www.example2.com');
}, false);
</script>
```

Comment: Post your **JS** code, and how you are calling **WebAppInterface()**

Comment: @CezaryGołaś Post the code along with the question by editing it. And try to put in more details about the problem you need to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Is so simple, sorry.

```
public static String k = "";
public void nextURL(String newURL){
        k = newURL;
    }

 public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;
      WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
      }
        public void showToast (String toast) {
          nextURL(toast);
        }
}
```